# Get language breakdown of all GitHub repositories by user

Tags: github

Is there a way to get the total language breakdown of all of a user's (specifically my) repositories in the same way as GitHub provides language breakdowns by repository? Or do I need to make one myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way directly on Github, and there are not many services out there for this sort of thing. There is a site called [coderstats.net](http://coderstats.net/) that may give you close to what you are looking for, though it is slightly different.

You can checkout [my profile](http://coderstats.net/github/Fogest/) for an example.

Comment: That's not quite what I was looking for, but I'll accept it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making my own solution to this. It can be found at jsnider3.github.io/GitHubBOC